# Widget to add, remove, and sort entries in a wxpython program

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm working on a program that outputs a text procedure file, based on user input. ie, the user will have a few options they can select from, and I'd like for them to be able to add them, reorder them, etc. into a custom order, and have it output that list into a text file.

I'd like to write this in python, and I am familiar with wxWidgets, but not tied to that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about some kind of list box with strings in it, then you might want to look at the EditableListBox, which is in wx.gizmos.EditableListBox. See the wxPython demo for more info.

Otherwise you'll have to roll your own, which really shouldn't be that hard.